# Как стилизовать ошибку required?

Tags: html, html5, required, стилизация

Есть такой input :

```
<input type="text" class="first-name" placeholder="Имя"pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" required>
```

Сейчас оно выводит сообщение : "Пожалуйста, используйте требуемый формат";

Как можно сделать так, что бы при ошибке оно выводило, например : "Имя должно содержать 2-20 символов"?'

Спасибо

Comment: каждый браузер имеет свой формат обработки `required` - для общей стилизации отключите этот атрибут и используйте проверку через javascript/php например

Comment: Изменить текст нельзя, это UI браузера. Да и вид уведомлений изменить без костылей сложно.
`Use the JS+CSS, Luke!`

Comment: Ответил на вопрос. Используйте setCustomValidity для данной задачи

Comment: Не знаю почему, но на всех браузерах работает, кроме Яндекс браузера... довольно странно...

Comment: Вы про setCustomValidity? У меня в я.браузере работает. А вот в Safari - ожидаемо нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете сделать вот таким образом:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Имя должно содержать 2-20 символов')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ух ты! А это костыль или нет?)

Comment: Почитайте про oninvalid. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_oninvalid.asp